# Assign java hashmap object to javascript object

Tags: java, javascript, hashmap

how to assign Hashmap object of java to object define in JS function and access that?

Comment: in which context? (JSP, GWT, other). please elaborate on the specific issue you're having.

Comment: You're mixing things, JavaScript has nothing to do with Java. Could you please elaborate a little more?